# getting Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id') error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I am getting this error again and again even trying different methods it is not getting fixed.

```
error message
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"
}
```

auth.js

```js
const Errorhandler = require("../utils/errorhandler");
const catchAsyncErrors = require("./catchasyncerror");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../model/usermodel");

exports.isAuthenticatedUser = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;

  if (!token) {
    return next(new Errorhandler("Please Login to access this resource", 401));
  }
  try {
    const decodedData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    req.user = await User.findById(decodedData.id);

    // Assuming "user_id" is the name of the cookie
    const userId = req.cookies.user_id;
    const name= req.user.name;

    // Set the user ID in req.user._id
    req.user._id = userId;
    req.user.name=name;

    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return next(new Errorhandler("Invalid token. Please login again.", 401));
  }
});

exports.authorizeRoles = (...roles) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
      return next(
        new Errorhandler(
          `Role: ${req.user.role} is not allowed to access this resource `,
          403
        )
      );
    }
    next();
  };
};
```

productcontroller.js

```js
exports.createProductReview = catchasyncerror(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { rating, comment, productId } = req.body;
  
    const review = {
      user: req.user._id,
      name: req.user.name,
      rating: Number(rating),
      comment,
    };
  
    const product = await Product.findById(productId);
  
    const isReviewed = product.reviews.find(
      (rev) => rev.user.toString() === req.user._id.toString()
    );
  
    if (isReviewed) {
      product.reviews.forEach((rev) => {
        if (rev.user.toString() === req.user._id.toString())
          (rev.rating = rating), (rev.comment = comment);
      });
    } else {
      product.reviews.push(review);
      product.numOfReviews = product.reviews.length;
    }
  
    let avg = 0;
  
    product.reviews.forEach((rev) => {
      avg += rev.rating;
    });
  
    product.ratings = avg / product.reviews.length;
  
    await product.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });
  
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
    });
  });
```

productmodel.js

```js
const mongoose=require("mongoose");

const productSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
    type:String,
    required:[true,"please enter product name"]
        },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,"please enter product description"]

    },
    price:{
        type:Number,
        required:[true,"please enter product description"],
        maxLength:[6,"please enter under limit"]
    },
    ratings:{
        type:String,
        default:0
    },
    images:[
     {
        publicId:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        imageurl:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        }
     }
    ],
    category:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,"please enter product category"],
        maxLength:[6,"please enter under limit"]
    },
    productStock:{
        type:Number,
        required:[true,"please enter product stock"],
        maxLength:[3,"please dont exceed product stock under 1000"]
    },
    numberofReviews:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
    reviews:[
        {
            // user: {
            //     type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            //     ref: "User",
            //     required: true,
            //   },
            name:{
                type:String,
                required:[true,"name should be there"]
            },
            rating:{
                type:Number,
                required:true
            },
            Comment:{
                type:String,
                required:true
            }
        }
    ],
    // user: {
    //     type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    //     ref: "User",
    //     required: true,
    //   },
    createdAt:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
})
module.exports=mongoose.model("product",productSchema);
```

Please help me with this issue.

I expected API to run successfully on put request but it is giving error that it is not reading data from cookie.

Even after replacing `req.user` with `req.auth` it's still not working.